# Django F() - avoid automatic parentheses

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I use F() for making calculations between database table columns. I build a formula using a loop. I add every F(column) to the formula in each loop cycle:

```
1. cycle: formula = F(col1)
2. cycle: formula += F(col2)
3. cycle: formula *= F(col3)
```

Then I use the formula in a query like this:

```
test = Model.objects.all().values('id').annotate(calc=formula)
```

When I do print(test.query), I get:

```
SELECT id, ((col1+col2)*col3) as calc FROM table;
```

The correct mathematical order would be:

```
(col1+(col2*col3))
```

How to keep the presedence in this case?

Comment: Normally the order would be `col_a + (col_b*col_c)` since the operator precedence is determed by the interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

> If you do something like this:
>
> ```
> Model.objects.all().values(id).anotate(calc=F(column_a)+F(column_b)*F(column_c))
> ```
>
> You will get a query like:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, ((column_a+column_b)*column_c) as calc FROM table;
> ```

Your assumption is **incorrect**. You can inspect the query with:

```
print(Model.objects.values('id').anotate(calc=F(column_a)+F(column_b)*F(column_c)).query)
```

and you will see that it constructs a query that looks like:

```
SELECT id, (column_a + (column_b * column_c))
FROM model
```

This is logical, since an object can *not* change the precedence of the operators. These are determined by the Python grammar. As you can see [Python's grammar on *binary arithmetic operators* [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) specifies that the `*` has higher precedence than `+`:

Comment: True, you are correct. If I print the query directlly from the code I get a result I gave in my question, but if I do a test in shell it works as you said. I have to do a little more research what is happening because I am constructing the formula programatically from a string. I'll update the question when I'll know more.

Comment: @Silko: I think the "string parser" that converts your string to an expression is then at fault (well that parser is apparently not taking precedence into account).

Comment: I found out where the problem is. The presedence is changed because of the loop. Parentheses are placed around the equation in each loop. How to keep the presedence in this case? I updated my question.

Comment: @Silko: you will need to change the algorithm. You can not do this with a single looping mechanism. You need something like a parser for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser So with a stack and shift and reduce rules.